# Import module from above folder does not work with CI server

Tags: python, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a working unit test python script under the folder "testing". In the unit python script I have sys.path.append("..") and then I import the module I want to test.

This work fine in my local machine but when I configure Gitlab CI server it does not find the module. Am I missing something?

Comment: Solved in a similar way as RedEyed:
from os import path
basepath = path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(basepath+"/..")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you add relative path.
Try to do (python 3.6):

```
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parents[1].resolve()))
```

Comment: Again it worked in my local computer but not in the server.

Comment: So, we can't help you until you describe us details.

Comment: Exactly this is the solution. I have not tested yours but I have just done a similar one:
from os import path
basepath = path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(basepath+"/..")

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

Since you are using a CI server you can set the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

This will make it so that your python code looks in other places for modules and packages, and then you can import them like your normally would. Just put your root directory in your PYTHONPATH and you'll be good to go

I do it in GitLab by setting a variable but you could always use do it by exporting the env var on the command before your script too.

### CI Config

```
stages:
    - SomeStage

SomeJob:
   stage: SomeStage
   image: "python:3.8"
   variables: "/builds/<user>/example_project"
   script:
       - python somedir/thingthatimportsfromroot.py
```

### Folder Structure

```
./example_project/
│
├── somedir/
│   ├── thingthatimportsfromroot.py
│
└── myimport.py
```

### thingthatimportsfromroot.py

```
import myimport

...
```